# Pandas Stack Column Number Mismatch

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[Try to stack and result in 3 columns not 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJg5r.png)
Hello, I am trying to use the stack function in pandas, but when I use it results in only 1 column when using shape, but displays 3. I see that they are on different levels and I have tried stuff with levels with no success. What can I do I need 3 columns!?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `new_cl_traff.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your screenshot you have a multi-index on your dataframe with  `year` and `month` - see the line where you name the two index levels:

`new_cl_traf.index.set_names(["Year","Month"], inplace=True)`

You can see the documentation for pandas.stack [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

if you use `new_cl_traff.reset_index()` the index or a subset of levels will be reset - see documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)